# Newly created Response Group Workflows do not get listed

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business, lync-server-2013

I am creating Response Group Workflows using **Remote PowerShell** in C#. Workflow gets created successfully and I get Workflow Identity in return.

But these workflows does not get listed using Get-RgsWorkflow command nor they are listing in Skype for Business Server Control Panel.

I have also tried

```
Get-CsRgsWorkflow  -ShowAll

Get-CsRgsWorkflow -Identity service:skypeserver.domain.com
```

But noting shows. 
However manually created workflows list properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that if we create a workflow as activated (Active = $true) then there are some mandatory parameters which we must have to pass while creating. Otherwise the workflows will not be created. For reference, please see the Microsoft documentation.
[New-CsRgsWorkflow](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398246.aspx)

Comment: i am glad you have figured it out.